# reading files into struct

Tags: c, file-io, struct

Hi I am recently making a program with c but I encounter some problems when dealing with text files. Here is my code(it's kinda long):

```
 struct std_choice
    {
        char id[6], choice1[3], choice2[3], choice3[3];
    };

    struct std_choice std1[1500]

    int load_std()
    {
        FILE *fp;
        int i=0,j=0,f=1, field=0, format=1, k, l, eof=0;
        char c;

    //initialization
    printf("  initializing array");
    for (k=0; k<1500; k++)
    {   for (l=0; l<6; l++)
        { std1[k].id[l]=0;
         };

         for (l=0; l<3; l++)
        { std1[k].choice1[l]=0;
         }; 

         for (l=0; l<3; l++)
        { std1[k].choice2[l]=0;
        }; 

         for (l=0; l<3; l++)
        { std1[k].choice3[l]=0;
        };

    };
    printf("finished\n");
    printf("  loading the file...");
    fp = fopen("std.txt", "rb");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {   printf("\n\nThe file does not exsist.; 
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {   printf("finished\n  loading student data");
        while (!eof && f && format)
        {    f=0; format=0;
             c= fgetc(fp);

                     if ((c !=58) && (c!=13) && (c!=-1))
             { 
             f = check_valid(&c, 1, 48, 57); // check if the character falls in the range 48-57

                       switch (field)
                       {    
                          case 0:      std1[j].id[i]=c;
                                           format = 1;
                                            break;
                              case 1:      std1[j].choice1[i]=c;
                                           format = 1;
                                            break;
                              case 2:      std1[j].choice2[i]=c;
                                           format = 1;
                                            break;
                              case 3:      std1[j].choice3[i]=c;
                                           format = 1;
                                            break;
                              default:     //error
                                            format=0;
                                            break;
                             };
                           i++;
                           }
                else
                        {   if (c==58)
                            {  
                               f=1;
                               switch (field)
                                { //check the no. of character read     
                                  case 0:  if (i==6) format=1;break;
                                  case 1:  if (i==3) format=1; break;
                                  case 2:  if (i==3) format=1; break;
                         default: format = 0; break;
                                 };
                               if (format==1)
                               field++;
                               i=0;
                              }
                              else   
                 {  //c==13  
                                if (c==13)
                                {  f=1;           
                                  c=fgetc(fp);

                                  if (i==3) //check if the no. of character read = 3
                                    {  format = 1;
                                      j++;
                                      field=0;
                                      i=0;
                                      if ((j%20) == 0) 
                                         printf(".");
                                    }
                                   else
                                      f=0;
                                   }
                                else 
                                {       //EOF
                                        eof=1;
                                        format=1;
                                        totalstd=j;
                                        f=1; 

                               };   
                             };
                        };  


           };

    };

    if (format ==0 || f==0)
    {
        return 0;
    };


    printf("finished\n");
    return 0; 
    };
```

And the text file is sth like this:

```
012345:000:000:000
123445:123:456:000
```

(with an enter before EOF)

Yet the result I get is really strange. for example,

```
std[0].id = 012345000000000123445123456000
std[0].choice1 = 000000000123445123456000
std[0].choice2 = 000123445123456000
```

I have tested the switch part and it seems that when I add the value of c to choice1 in case 1, c is added to id too... is there any way to fix this?

Comment: This is the worst possible implementation of parsing a file. Look into functions like `fgets()` and `strtok_r()`. Also, don't hard-code ASCII values of characters and EOF, it's wrong. Use character literals. (**Why,** seriously, why do people find it easier to read `48` than `'0'` when they meant `'0'`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't consider NULL character in your strings, the struct should be like this:

```
 struct std_choice
    {
        char id[7], choice1[4], choice2[4], choice3[4];
    };
```

**Why did it work that way?**

Struct members are stored in memory in order you declared them (sometimes with extra padding).
Assume you store `012345:abc:def:ghi` into your struct, Memory Will look like this:

```
                   V choice2
_______________________________
|0|1|2|3|4|5|a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i| ...
-------------------------------
 ^ id        ^           ^
             choice1     choice3
```

When you read `id` and print it, printf function will start reading and printing characters from memory starting from where `id` points to till it reaches a `NULL` character, so it will print `012345abcdefhgi...`, it may read from next struct too (it happened in your sample), similarly, when you wanna print `choice1`, it will start from `a` and go on till it reaches a `NULL` (resulting `abcdefghi...`) and so on...